# How do I trigger sending TestNG emailable report after test completion

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, testng

How do I send TestNG emailable report through mail automatcally after completetion.

I have the logic for sending email, but that email is not triggering after completion of test suite execution. Please help me with the logic

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I have used IReporter listener but still did not able to send the latest report through email because emailable report is not refreshed. So before sending that to user, I am opening emailable report using below

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("file:"+filename1));
```

filename1 is the emailable report file.

Now I am able to get the latest one....

Comment: What packages to import??